# Woocommerce: Get all info related to the Product that was added to Cart using Add to Cart button

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

On the Wordpress homepage, there is a section called Best Sellers that showcases best sellers in the website. In summary, these are nothing but various products with Add to Cart link, in Woocommerce loop. **When this Add to Cart link is clicked, I need to be able to read all information regarding the product that was just now added to cart, such as its ID, Quantity, Variant ID, etc. via AJAX or however Wordpress/Woocommerce does it WITHOUT reloading the page.**

**NOTE:**

Please note whatever function is used to accomplish this task, should not interfere with the functionality of Single Product page when the Add to Cart button in Single Product page is clicked. It is completely fine if the desired functionality cascades to other parts of the website such as Shop, Archive, etc. but **NOT** the Single Product page.

**WHAT I TRIED:**

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_loop_add_to_cart', 21);
function my_loop_add_to_cart() {
    //What code should I write here to access the recently added to cart item? 
}
```

***I am ok with changing the hook if the need be, just want to make sure that it does not interfere with the functionality of the Add to Cart link/button in the Single Product page.***

Comment: why not get the cart instead and loop through its items?

Comment: @Reigel Because I just want to process the data of only the item that was just added to cart and not the other items that may already exist in cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options to do this.
One I can think of is using `woocommerce_add_to_cart` action hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'rmg_woocommerce_add_to_cart', 10, 6 );
function rmg_woocommerce_add_to_cart( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ){
    // do something with $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I am already aware of the above action. In fact, I also tried it already and found out that whatever code I write in it, affects/interferes the Add to Cart functionality in the Single Product page as well. That's why I can't use that function. Do you know of anything else that might be useful? What is the other option?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to read the quantities of each product that the customer has added to cart and based on that info, offer him different in-house options for purchase.  Does that make sense?

Comment: you have the `$product_id` and `$quantity` in that action hook, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: For now, the issue seems to be fixed. Thanks for the solution. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is one hook named `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` which will work for related products and shop page products listing only.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 9 );


function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart()
{
   global $woocommerce;
   $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
   $last_added_item_details = end($items)['data'];
}
```

Tested and works well

Comment: How can I access the details of the item that was just added to cart using your code?

Comment: please check updated answer and print variable `$items`

Comment: That will print all the cart items. I just need to access the information of **ONLY** the current item that was just added to cart and not the other items that already exist in cart. The code `$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();` does **NOT** give me the info of the product that was just added to cart by clicking on the Add to Cart button. Makes sense?